# Parsing an XML using XPath / DOM / SAX

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, sax

I have an xml that I need to Parse and fetch values from it. However , I am not sure which way of parsing would be the best for the xml of this type. I read about different ways but not sure if that's the best possible way. Could someone please help me write a java code to Parse this xml using the best approach ? 
Thanks in advance !

Here's the XML :

```
<managementDomain>
    <mtosi:additionalInfo>
            <mtosi:nvs>
                <stru:attributeName>Managed Device Name</stru:attributeName>
                <stru:attributeValue>
                    <nonc:value>al-dcdc-numr-phe-eu</nonc:value>
                </stru:attributeValue>
            </mtosi:nvs>
            <mtosi:nvs>
                <stru:attributeName>NMDBF</stru:attributeName>
                <stru:attributeValue>
                    <nonc:value>Y</nonc:value>
                </stru:attributeValue>
            </mtosi:nvs>
            <mtosi:nvs>
                <stru:attributeName>BFGCustrID</stru:attributeName>
                <stru:attributeValue>
                    <nonc:value>3444</nonc:value>
                </stru:attributeValue>
            </mtosi:nvs>
            <mtosi:nvs>
                <stru:attributeName>BFGContractID</stru:attributeName>
                <stru:attributeValue>
                    <nonc:value>12331</nonc:value>
                </stru:attributeValue>
            </mtosi:nvs>
      </mtosi:additionalInfo>
    <mtosi:mdVendorExtensions>
        <mtosi:tmf854Version/>
        <mtosi:extVersion/>
        <mtosi:extAuthor/>
    </mtosi:mdVendorExtensions>
    <mtosi:managedElement>
        <mtosi:manufacturer>
            <nonc:ossValue>CISCO</nonc:ossValue>
        </mtosi:manufacturer>
        <mtosi:productName>
            <nonc:value>CISCO2951</nonc:value>
        </mtosi:productName>
        <mtosi:meVendorExtensions>
            <mtosi:tmf854Version/>
            <mtosi:extVersion/>
            <mtosi:extAuthor/>
            <mtosi:managementIPAddress>
                <mtosi:ipValue>
                    <nonc:value>10.32.22.49</nonc:value>
                </mtosi:ipValue>
            </mtosi:managementIPAddress>
        </mtosi:meVendorExtensions>
    </mtosi:managedElement>
</managementDomain>
```

I need to fetch :

ManagementIpAddress , BFGCustomerId , BFGContractID and Managed Device Name from this xml

Comment: use [`Element#getElementsByTagName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29) to get the tag elements using its name.

Comment: Your question is not a good fit for SO as it is primarily opinion based. You could use all of the technologies you mention and which one you use is up to you and your requirements and skills. Any technology should do for such a simply XML. Also, we do not provide complete code for your - Please try it yourself first and if you run into problems, we are happy to help you with them.

Comment: @dirkk - If you can help please and thanks for your valuable suggestion , I broke my head to get till here ! Need your expert advise on the above query please

Comment: <getDiscrepancyManagedElementByNameRequest xmlns="http://capabilities.nat.bt.com/xsd/ManageDiscoveryAndDiscrepancyCheck/2009/06/22" xmlns:mtosi="http://capabilities.nat.bt.com/xsd/ManageDiscoveryAndDiscrepancyCheck/2009/06/22/MTOSI" xmlns:stru="http://capabilities.nat.bt.com/xsd/ManageDiscoveryAndDiscrepancyCheck/2009/06/22/MTOSI/Structs" xmlns:nonc="http://capabilities.nat.bt.com/xsd/ManageDiscoveryAndDiscrepancyCheck/2009/06/22/NONCCM" xmlns:head="http://wsi.nat.bt.com/2005/06/StandardHeader/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

removing this from my xml xpath works fine

Comment: MY XPATh expression is :

/getDiscrepancyManagedElementByNameRequest/managementDomain/mtosi_additionalInfo/mtosi_nvs[stru_attributeName='Managed Device Name']/stru_attributeValue/nonc_value/text()

Do you see any reason why it wont parse with this ? This xml will flow as a request from upstream to me and will contain this data. Can you give some pointers please ?

Comment: If you have a different question, please ask a new question. Otherwise, please edit your question - The XML and Xpath in the comments is unreadable. However, your question was put on hold because it currently does not fit the format of SO; we don't give recommendation such as the ones you requested.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible ways of parsing this XML are DOM4J and SAX. The former is more memory intensive and loads the complete document into a Java object structure. With SAX you can parse the file by Streaming the content and "listening" for the Elements you want to extract.

So for your specific case - that is reading only some few elements - SAX might be the way to go.

The drawback of SAX is, that invites to some hackish solutions that only work with specific - and correct (i.e. in the best case pre-validated) XML files. You need to programm more carefully when using SAX.

(Of course with small XMLs it's not a shame to load it completly with DOM4J, if this is more convenient for you ;)